# Recover Lost Public Folder

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, public-folders

I have a public folder that seems for all intents and purposes to be lost.  It does not seem to appear in the Public Folder Management Console.  It is mail enabled so I can use Get-MailPublicFolder and I will see it.  I also see it in Microsoft Exchange System Objects in ADUC.  But, I can't see to do anything else with it.  If I try to get the actual public folder object with Get-PublicFolder, it won't find it.  If I do a Get-MailPublicFolder StorageFile | Get-PublicFolder I get the following error:

```
No existing 'PublicFolder' matches the following Identity: '/O=PORT AUTHORITY/OU=FIRST ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP/CN=RECIPIEN
TS/CN=STORAGE FILEC0C97C0044AD2E4CC8A6FC9C5633743300004A'. Make sure that you specified the correct 'PublicFolder' Iden
tity and that you have the necessary permissions to view 'PublicFolder'.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0:Int32) [Get-PublicFolder], MapiObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : D5E9AC0A,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.MapiTasks.GetPublicFolder
```

I am using an account with Domain Admin and Exchange Admin rights.  This is probably an old public folder brought over from Exchange 2003.  How can I remove it or make it visible?

Edit: It may be that the mail object exists in AD for the folder but the actual folder no longer exists in the Exchange Public Folder DB.  If I do Get-PublicFolder \ -Recurse or Get-PublicFolder \NON_IPM_SUBTREE -Recurse I don't find the folder.